# htaccess redirection matching urls to grandparent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

A search engine keeps hitting my site regularly for non-existing pages that it randomly generates. I want to put an end to this silliness using a 301 rule in my htaccess file.

The most usual address is 
site.tld/blog/welcome-back/**x**/xx/ 
where x is a random number but sometimes I get hits on 
site.tld/blog/welcome-back/**xx**/xx/
or text instead of numbers.

I want to redirect all these hits to the real existing page
/blog/welcome-back/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are those /x/y/ URLs ever supposed to be valid?  If so, you probably won't want an `.htaccess` file redirect.  If not, why are they being generated?

Comment: In short, all `http://site.tld/blog/welcome-back/anything` must be redirected to `http://site.tld/blog/welcome-back/` regardless of the content of `anything`. Is that right or is it necessary to keep some content in some cases?

Comment: hrunting: No, they aren't. Like I said those are randomly generated by the search engine. Only /blog/welcome-back/ exists.

Comment: faa: Yes, that's it. Any request with something after /blog/welcome-back/ must redirect to the welcome-back page.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/welcome-back/.+$ http://site.tld/blog/welcome-back/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @bradym but it's only working for /blog/welcome-back/something/ and not for /blog/welcome-back/something/more/